# VMWare ESX 3.5 - how to configure VM vSwitch for teaming?

Tags: vmware-esx, bonding

I thought I could figure this out but can't.

I'm trying to take vmnic2 and vmnic3 and create a vSwitch for just the VM's to use.

I can do this part just fine.

But I can't seem to team them together.  I was told that I should create the teaming on the switch (an Extreme Networks x450 switch) but when I do so (whether as L2 or L3 team) I can no longer route outside the switch.

Without the switch teaming on the network switch everything routes fine (from my workstation for example to the VM).  Once I enable port sharing/teaming though I can no longer get to the VM from my workstation or vice versa.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

In an Extreme Networks switch the proper command is:

> enable sharing  grouping  algorithm address-based L3

This will ensure it uses IP based port sharing.

Then in the Virtual Switch properties, set the Load Balancing setting to "Route based on ip hash".

That took care of it and allows for both inbound and outbound load balancing.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not configuring your switch for LACP teaming.  It needs to be "hard set" to a team.  VMware does not support LACP teams.

Comment: ESX 3.x does support 802.3ad and LACP in STATIC configurations.

Comment: No, it's basic L2 address-based teaming.  If I do it for a physical server with 2 nics it works but the same teaming doesn't seem to work for vmware.

Is there something to configure in the vswitch settings as well?